# Is there an Ifilter for Nuance PDFs to be used in junction with SharePoint2010?

Tags: search, crawling, pdf, ifilter

I know that there are ifilters for Adobe PDF files and hence make these files searchable inside Sharepoint.  Have not tried them but is there an ifilter for nuance created PDF documents? Please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The Adobe IFilter allows to index all searchable PDF files (i.e. not the ones created by scanning a document or a book), regardless of  software that was used to generate them.